# How do i save byte info of jpg and how can i later use those bytes data to create an same image just by the help of bytes

Tags: python, byte

```
with open("image.jpg", 'rb') as original_file:
    original = original_file.read()

# write part
with open("dubs.jpg", 'wb') as duplicate_file:
    duplicate_file.write(original)
```

#directly if i pass original to write and create an image it'll work. But i want to save that byte information and able to recreate the same image using same byte data, even if im on different pc.

Comment: What do you mean by "save that byte information"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Does this work for your case?

```
import base64

file_name = '<image_file_path>'

# open the file as bytes
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
    in_jpg_encoding = f.read()

# Encode the bytes object to base64 
base64_encoding = base64.b64encode(in_jpg_encoding)

# Store the base64 encoding in text file
with open("base64.txt", "wb") as fw:
    fw.write(base64_encoding)

# -------------------------------------------------

# Open the base64 encoding text file
with open("base64.txt", 'rb') as f:
    result = f.read()

# Apply the base64 decoding
out_b64_decoding = base64.b64decode(result)

# Store the file as .jpg
with open("recreate.jpg", "wb") as fw:
    fw.write(out_b64_decoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to convert any type of image files to bytes :

```
import base64

with open("example.png", "rb") as imageFile:
bytes = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
print(bytes)
```

then you can convert the "bytes" variable resulted from the above code by using the following :

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(bytes)))
image.save('output\\path\\example.png', 'PNG')
```